# how do i mock a json post request in ring?

Tags: clojure, ring

I'm using peridot - https://github.com/xeqi/peridot to test my ring application, and its working fine until I try to mock a post request with json data:

```
(require '[cheshire.core :as json])
(use 'compojure.core)

(defn json-post [req]
  (if (:body req)
    (json/parse-string (slurp (:body req)))))

(defroutes all-routes
  (POST "/test/json" req  (json-response (json-post req))))

(def app (compojure.handler/site all-routes))

(use 'peridot.core)

(-> (session app)
    (request "/test/json"
             :request-method :post
             :body (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream. (.getBytes "hello" "UTF-8")))
```

gives `IOException: stream closed`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## tldr:

```
(-> (session app)
    (request "/test/json"
             :request-method :post
             :content-type "application/json"
             :body (.getBytes "\"hello\"" "UTF-8")))
```

---

When peridot generates a request map it will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for the content-type for a `:post` request. With the app as specified `wrap-params` (which is included by `compojure.handler/site`) will attempt to read the `:body` in order to parse any form-urlencoded parameters. Then `json-post` attempts to read the `:body` again.  However `InputStream`s are designed to be read once, and that causes the exception.

There are basically two ways to solve the issue:

1. Remove `compojure.handler/site`.
2. Add a content type to the request (as done in the tldr)

Answer (score 5):

```
(require '[cheshire.core :as json])

(-> (session app)
    (request "/test/json"
             :request-method :post
             :content-type "application/json"
             :body (json/generate-string data))
```

No need to call `.getBytes`, just pass json with `:body` parameter.