# Compojure-api not respecting body from ring.mock.requests

Tags: clojure, ring, compojure-api

I'm trying to use the ring.mock.requests library to test an http service. I have this bit of code

```
   (auth-routes    
     (->
       (mock/request :post "/auth/user")
       (mock/body {:username "user" :password "pass"})
       (mock/content-type "application/json")))
```

The inner part with the thread-first macro seems to work correctly, but it fails when I try to make the mock request to auth-routes

And this is my route:

```
(def auth-routes
  (context "/auth" []
  :tags ["Authentication"]
    (POST "/user" []
      :return s/Uuid
      :body [request m/User]
      :summary "Create new user"
      (ok (auth/create-user request)))) ...)
```

This is my schema:

```
(def User {:username s/Str
           :password s/Str})
```

The exception I'm seeing is

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo
   Request validation failed
   {:error (not (map? nil)), :type :compojure.api.exception/request-validation}
```

It looks like my route is getting `nil` as the body, and I expect `{:username "user" :password "pass"}` to be there.

What am I doing wrong and how do I pass a body to this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should serialize your data as a json string in your test. Using [cheshire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire):

```
(cheshire.core/generate-string {:username "user" :password "pass"})
```

Take a look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/Jch0COgRIj0) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035319/how-do-i-mock-a-json-post-request-in-ring).

Comment: Is your `auth-routes` definition correct? Shouldn't your `POST "/user" []` be something like `POST "/user" request`?

Comment: It is correct by the compojure-api examples [here](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api)

Comment: OK, I think you need serialization. Take a look [here](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api/wiki/Testing-api-endpoints#testing-post-endpoint). Also I've created a small [repo](https://github.com/kongeor/compringmock) to test it and it is working.

Comment: Your example works for me, but when I remove the serialization, I get a different error. I see in your example you're using the `api` function to wrap the routes, which I don't do here because I'm pulling them together elsewhere. Because I'm missing that, the :body parameter for compojure-api isn't being respected (of course).